# Why is xhr.response set to null if a warning arises in my PHP code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

For clarification: **the .php files are my professor's and are intended NOT to be changed.** The problem arises because `$VALORES` in line 186 is uninitialized, and I already issued it to my professor.

This is the code:

- nueva.html:

```html
<form onsubmit="crearPublicacion(event);">
    <div>
        <label>Título:</label>
        <input type="text" name="titulo">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Texto:</label>
        <textarea name="texto"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Zona:</label>
        <input type="text" name="zona">
    </div>
    <div id="fotos">
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="fotos[]" accept="image/*">
            <textarea name="descripciones[]"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="fotos[]" accept="image/*">
            <textarea name="descripciones[]"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="fotos[]" accept="image/*">
            <textarea name="descripciones[]"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

- nueva.js:

```js
function crearPublicacion(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();   // Cancela el comportamiento por defecto

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = 'api/publicaciones',
        fd  = new FormData(evt.currentTarget),
        usu = JSON.parse(sessionStorage['_datos_']),
        auth = `${usu.LOGIN}:${usu.TOKEN}`;
    
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = (evt) => {
        let r = xhr.response;

        console.log(r);
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

- publicaciones.php:

```php
<?php
require_once('../inc/config.php'); // Constantes, etc ...
require_once('../inc/database.php');

$db    = new Database();
$dbCon = $db->getConnection();
$dbCon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$RECURSO = explode("/", substr($_GET['prm'],1));
$headers = apache_request_headers();
if(isset($headers['Authorization']))
    $AUTORIZACION = $headers['Authorization'];
elseif (isset($headers['authorization']))
    $AUTORIZACION = $headers['authorization'];

if(!isset($AUTORIZACION))
{ // Acceso no autorizado
  $RESPONSE_CODE    = 403;
  $R['RESULTADO']   = 'ERROR';
  $R['CODIGO']      = $RESPONSE_CODE;
  $R['DESCRIPCION'] = 'Falta autorización';
}
else
{
  $R             = [];  // Almacenará el resultado.
  $RESPONSE_CODE = 200; // código de respuesta por defecto: 200 - OK
  $PARAMS = $_POST;
  list($login,$token) = explode(':', $AUTORIZACION);

  if( !$db->comprobarSesion($login,$token) )
  {
    $RESPONSE_CODE    = 401;
    $R['RESULTADO']   = 'ERROR';
    $R['CODIGO']      = $RESPONSE_CODE;
    $R['DESCRIPCION'] = 'Error de autenticación.';
  }
  else
  {
    $ID = array_shift($RECURSO);
    try{
      $dbCon->beginTransaction();
      if(!is_numeric($ID)) // NUEVO REGISTRO
      { // Si no es numérico $ID es porque se está creando un nuevo registro
        $titulo        = $PARAMS['titulo'];
        $texto         = nl2br($PARAMS['texto'],false);
        $zona          = $PARAMS['zona'];
        $descripciones = $PARAMS['descripciones'];

        $mysql = 'select * from zona where nombre=:ZONA';
        $RESPUESTA = $db->select($mysql, [':ZONA'=>$zona]);
        if( $RESPUESTA['CORRECTO'] ) // execute query OK
        {
          if(count($RESPUESTA['RESULT']) > 0)
          { // encontrado
            $idZona = $RESPUESTA['RESULT'][0]['id'];
          }
          else
          { // No existe la zona. Hay que crearla.
            $mysql = 'insert into zona(nombre) values(:NOMBRE)';
            if( $db->executeStatement($mysql, [':NOMBRE'=>$zona]) )
            {
              $mysql = 'select max(id) as idZona from zona';
              $RESPUESTA = $db->select($mysql, $VALORES);
              if( $RESPUESTA['CORRECTO'] ) // execute query OK
              {
                if(count($RESPUESTA['RESULT']) > 0)
                { // encontrado
                  $idZona = $RESPUESTA['RESULT'][0]['idZona'];
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        $mysql  = 'insert into publicacion(titulo,texto,idZona,autor) ';
        $mysql .= 'values(:TITULO,:TEXTO,:ID_ZONA,:AUTOR)';
        $VALORES             = [];
        $VALORES[':TITULO']  = $titulo;
        $VALORES[':TEXTO']   = $texto;
        $VALORES[':ID_ZONA'] = $idZona;
        $VALORES[':AUTOR']   = $login;

        if( $db->executeStatement($mysql, $VALORES) )
        {
          $mysql = "select MAX(id) as id_pub from publicacion";
          $RESPUESTA = $db->select($mysql);
          if($RESPUESTA['CORRECTO'])
          {
            $ID = $RESPUESTA['RESULT'][0]['id_pub'];

            $RESPONSE_CODE    = 201;
            $R['RESULTADO']   = 'OK';
            $R['CODIGO']      = $RESPONSE_CODE;
            $R['DESCRIPCION'] = 'Registro creado correctamente';
            $R['ID']          = $ID;
            $R['TITULO']      = $titulo;
            $R['FOTOS']       = $fotos;
          }
          else
            $ID = -1;
        }
        else
        {
          $RESPONSE_CODE    = 500; // INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
          $R['RESULTADO']   = 'ERROR';
          $R['CODIGO']      = $RESPONSE_CODE;
          $R['DESCRIPCION'] = 'Error indefinido al crear el nuevo registro';
        }
      }
      $dbCon->commit();
    }catch(Exception $e){
      echo $e;
      $dbCon->rollBack();
    }
  }
}
$dbCon = null;
http_response_code($RESPONSE_CODE);
echo json_encode($R);
?>
```

- database.php:

```php
<?php
class Database{
    private $HOST              = "127.0.0.1";
    private $DB_DATABASE_NAME  = "websocial";
    private $DB_USERNAME       = "pcw";
    private $DB_PASSWORD       = "pcw";
    public  $conn;

    public function __construct() {...}

    public function select($query = "" , $params = [])
    {
        $result = false;
        $RESPUESTA = [];

        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
            if($stmt === false) {
                throw New Exception("Unable to do prepared statement: " . $query);
            }

            $stmt->execute($params);

            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            $RESPUESTA['CORRECTO'] = true;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            // throw New Exception( $e->getMessage() );
            $RESPUESTA['CORRECTO'] = false;
            $RESPUESTA['ERROR'] = $e->getMessage();
        }

        $RESPUESTA['RESULT'] = $result;

        return $RESPUESTA;
    }

    public function executeStatement($query = "", $params = [])
    {
        $retVal = false;
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
 
            if($stmt === false) {
                throw New Exception("Unable to do prepared statement: " . $query);
            }
 
            if( $params )
                $retVal = $stmt->execute($params);
            else
                $retVal = $stmt->execute();

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            throw New Exception( $e->getMessage() );
        }   

        return $retVal;
    }

}
?>
```

As you can see, `$VALORES` (publicacion.php) has not been initialized when calling `select` in line 186 (that is the warning it gives me whenever I try to do a POST in Postman). The solution is as easy as to remove $VALORES altogether.

To give you an idea, this is the expected result:

```json
{
    "RESULTADO": "OK",
    "CODIGO": 201,
    "DESCRIPCION": "Registro creado correctamente",
    "ID": 109,
    "TITULO": "",
    "FOTOS": []
}
```

But this is what happens only when the value for "zona" does not exist yet in the database (if it already exists, then the response is always the above):

- Postman:

> Warning: Undefined variable $VALORES in C:\xampp\htdocs\pcw\practica2\api\post\publicaciones.php on line 186

```json
{
    "RESULTADO": "OK",
    "CODIGO": 201,
    "DESCRIPCION": "Registro creado correctamente",
    "ID": 109,
    "TITULO": "",
    "FOTOS": []
}
```

- JS console in VSCode debugger / Web DevTools:

```js
null
```

---

As I stated before, I already solved the problem, but my question is about why does it happen and where exactly.

What moment my `xhr.response` sets to `null`? The only explanation I could find is that rising a warning somehow nullifies the response even if the code is running alright (i.e., without falling into catch and throw statements and without exiting at all).

Comment: Unrelated but you REALLY need to stop checking manually for errors. Remove `if($stmt === false) {` as it's not only unnecessary but it leaks sensitive information to your end users.

Comment: Are you asking why `$VALORES` is undefined or why you get NULL in JavaScript. Your questions doesn't seem related to MySQL so it should not be tagged as such. If you are asking about the undefined variable then the answer is to just remove it from that line.

Comment: `$_GET['prm']` But you are POSTing from the browser and you have no field names that

Comment: No real "mystery" here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType#value: _"When setting responseType to a particular value, the author should make sure that the server is actually sending a response compatible with that format. If the server returns data that is not compatible with the responseType that was set, the value of response will be null."_ You told the browser the response _would be_ JSON, but your server responded with "random gibberish followed by some JSON", and _that_ is of course _not_ valid JSON.

Comment: @Dharman The .php files are my professor's and they are intended to not be changed (although if there is something that is making the system malfunction, then I have to request a change, of course, like in this case), so I must not change what you said, but I appreciate it since in the future I will be asked to code in PHP so thank you.

Comment: Tell your professor that they are teaching bad practices and they should take a look at the PHP manual and get up to date. The school is doing you a disservice by teaching you how to write bad PHP code.

Comment: @Dharman I know why `$VALORES` is undefined, what I ask is why I get `null` in the JS console when I use an undefined variable whilst everything else works fine. That being said, I tagged this with MySQL *just to be sure*, but I will happily untag it as such if it is unrelated. Thank you.

Comment: @Dharman Yes, they should. I'm no PHP expert (a newbie actually), yet I can see that the API lacks many things. Don't worry: I will not learn anything out of the .php files, I hope they will teach it correctly whenever I DO have to code in PHP.

Comment: @CBroe Oh, I see. So the HTML from the warning that the server sends is why it is `null` in the JS console. I see, thank you! Now: what shall I do? Do I ask you to make it an answer so that I can mark it as answered or should I make an answer explaining it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType#value:

> When setting responseType to a particular value, the author should make sure that the server is actually sending a response compatible with that format. If the server returns data that is not compatible with the responseType that was set, the value of response will be null.

With `xhr.responseType = 'json';` you told the browser, that the response would be JSON, and that it should automatically parse it as such for you.

But "random PHP warning message followed by some JSON" is not valid JSON. And so it set the value of your response to null.